# Insert easing to a video

Tags: ffmpeg, easing

I'm using `ffmpeg` to create a video from a sequence of images, using the command:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i e%02d.jpg -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p outputVideo.mp4
```

Is it possible to add a `ease-in-out` to the video?

**EDIT**

To the "unclear vote": This command makes a slideshow, each image will have the same screen time, I want to make the firsts and the lasts images with more screen time.

Its now more clear?